# How to make a smooth animation on a list in Android?

Tags: android, listview, animation, gridview

I have implemented an animation for a `Layout` that must flow downwards and upwards. The animation precisely must flow in both low that high. This gridview is located above a `ExpandbleListView`. So, when I close all the groups the animation is very fluid. When the groups on the list are open, with many elements, however the animation is triggered, it is not as fluid as I would like it to be. I'll post the code of my animation:

```
    public void expand(final View v) {
    v.measure(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targtetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

    v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1 ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    : (int) (targtetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    Interpolator i = AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(this,
            android.R.anim.linear_interpolator);
    a.setInterpolator(i);
    a.setDuration(200);
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

and :

```
public static void collapse(final View v) {
    final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();
    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime,
                Transformation t) {
            if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight
                        - (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration(200);
    v.startAnimation(a);
}
```

How can I do to make the animation smoother?

--> Edit: I was wrong code, I corrected

Comment: have you tried `setFillEnabled(true)` instead of `setFillAfter()`?

Comment: I had the wrong code, now I corrected

Comment: I'm sorry your solution does not work, I had already tried to do in this